# I am trying to fetch data include image in codeigniter and want to show on page

Tags: php, codeigniter

After inserting data in db i want to fetch and show it on view page how can i show please check my code if anything wrong please let me know...

### Model Code is

```
function getAboutus(){
    $query=$this->db->select('title')->from('aboutus')->get();
    return $query->result;       
}
```

### Controller Code is

```
public function index()
{
    $aboutusdata = $this->AboutusModel->getAboutus();
    $data = array();
    $data['content'] = "admin/aboutus";
    $this->load->view('admin/main',$data, ['aboutus'=>$aboutusdata]);
}
```

### View Code is

```
<tbody>
    <?php if(!empty($aboutusdata)): foreach($aboutusdata as $aboutus): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo '#'.$aboutus['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (strlen($aboutus['detail'])>150)?substr($aboutus['detail'],0,150).'...':$aboutus['detail']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['image']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['img_heading']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['created']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['modified']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; else: ?>
    <tr><td colspan="8">About US Record(s) not found......</td></tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: instead of result use result_array() in Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller code, you have to pass like as below:

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['aboutusdata'] = $this->AboutusModel->getAboutus();
    $data['content'] = "admin/aboutus";
    $this->load->view('admin/main',$data);
}
```

Just set your variable `aboutusdata` with `$data` and assign it with your `view`.
 As per your variable in view, you will get values from `$aboutusdata`.

**Model**

```
function getAboutus(){
    $query=$this->db->select('title')->from('aboutus')->get();
    return $query->result_array();       
}
```

**View**

```
<tbody>
    <?php if(!empty($aboutusdata)): foreach($aboutusdata as $aboutus): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo '#'.$aboutus['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (strlen($aboutus['detail'])>150)?substr($aboutus['detail'],0,150).'...':$aboutus['detail']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['image']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['img_heading']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['created']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aboutus['modified']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; else: ?>
    <tr><td colspan="8">About US Record(s) not found......</td></tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be like this ;

```
public function index()
{
    $aboutusdata = $this->AboutusModel->getAboutus();
    $data = array();
    $data['aboutusdata'] = $aboutusdata;
    $data['content'] = "admin/aboutus";
    $this->load->view('admin/main',$data);
}
```

In model should be like this : `result_array()`

```
function getAboutus(){
    $query=$this->db->select('title')->from('aboutus')->get();
    return $query->result_array();       
}
```

Comment: Thanks pradeep to you too

Comment: But in virb answer there are complete set of MVC... so that i implement as it is.

Comment: its ok , but we can provide you just hint of the answer ,can not  write the whole code or structure, i provide u what is necessary for the answer